# Where can I find disease diagnosis datasets?

Tags: epidemiology, data, infectious-diseases, vector

For an epidemiological study, I'm looking for datasets for any kind of vector-borne disease (i.e. West Nile Virus, Malaria, etc.), or any parasites that are dependent on intermediate hosts (i.e. *Schistosoma spp.*, which have snails as intermediate hosts).

The data should include day or week and location of each diagnosis. I have been able to find diagnosis data for individual countries for each year, but I'm looking for daily or weekly data for city-wide resolution or at least smaller regions inside countries.

Additionally, it does not matter what country/continent the data is for, as long as there are many data points (i.e. at least 10,000). For example, if there is a lot of good data for Brazil, that's fine.

Does anyone know if such information exists, and if so, where I can find it? I've been searching for it for the past month but have had little luck with finding anything useful. Any help and guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Can you reveal some typical keywords to help with the search?

Comment: @Jan Maybe things like: "malaria outbreak dataset" or "malaria diagnosis dataset"? I'm not entirely sure what the best way to word this Google search is, either, which is severely limiting what I can find

Comment: I was thinking about synonyms for _dataset_ and other keywords that help to find the _type_ of data you are looking for. I'm very familiar with the medical terminology, but not with statistical one. Also can you show an example you've already found?

Comment: Is this close: https://data.gov.in/keywords/malaria ?

Comment: @Jan Hi again Jan, sorry for the late reply. That website's great! I didn't bookmark any of the sites I searched thorugh, so I'm having a hard time finding them again to share with you - but they weren't as good as yours; the best one contained monthly data for countries, not regions. Do you know if this kind of data is available for other countries (not just India)? I'm also looking for it, but in case you already have them. Lastly, add this as an answer :)

Comment: NIAID has released a new open data discovery portal and you can search or filter by disease, host species, etc. https://data.niaid.nih.gov/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**CDC Wonder**](https://wonder.cdc.gov/), a health database of the US Center of Disease Control and Prevention (CDC), has weekly data for [Nationally Notifiable Infectious Diseases and Conditions, United States: Weekly Tables](https://wonder.cdc.gov/nndss/nndss_weekly_tables_menu.asp?mmwr_year=2020&mmwr_week=06) from 1996 to 2020 on the state level for antrax, brucellosis, dengue fever, leptospirosis, malaria, meningococcal disease, Q fever, rabies, etc.

Weekly tables since 2014 are available on [**Data.CDC.gov**](https://data.cdc.gov/browse?q=NNDSS&sortBy=newest&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Weekly tables for 1952-2017 published in the MMWR are available at [**CDC Stacks MMWR**](https://stacks.cdc.gov/cbrowse/?parentId=cdc:101&pid=cdc:101) and weekly tables starting in 2018 are available at [**CDC Stacks NNDSS**](https://stacks.cdc.gov/gsearch?parentId=cdc%3A49375&pid=cdc%3A49375&genre=Weekly%20Reports).

[**HealthData.gov**](https://healthdata.gov/) has two weekly datasets for malaria by US states - [here is one](https://healthdata.gov/dataset/nndss-table-1v-malaria-measles-indigenous).

[**Open Government Data (OGD) Platform India**](https://data.gov.in/) has data on a district or state level, for example, for [malaria](https://data.gov.in/keywords/malaria).

Keywords that can help in further search:

- infectious disease
- week or weekly report or data
- MMWR (Morbidity and Mortality Weekly Report)
- surveillance

Keywords, like diagnosis or outbreak, can limit your search too much.